# Can built ios app in ubuntu with flutter framework?

Tags: flutter

I'm new in Ios development and flutter. I want to make an app for ios. I've Ubuntu system and already app coded in the dart language. Now Is that possible to build ios app for the test in a real device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an OSX machine with XCode to build iOS executable.
You can use a cheap Mac Mini or hosted solutions for that step,
but there is no way to do it with Ubuntu only.

Comment: Is that possible with VMware or virtual box?

Comment: If I have a mac then do I need to invest any bucks for a developer account. I mean to say can i run the simulator on a mac without the developer account.

Comment: As far as I know you need the account only when you want to publish to the AppStore. I was able to run Flutter apps in the Simulator and I don't have a developer account.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it unless you use an external tool for example: [Odevio](https://github.com/Odevio/Odevio-CLI). It's a python utility that let's you access a Mac build machine. It's pretty easy to use.

If you have Odevio installed you can start to build directly in the build menu.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your ubuntu system is running on Apple Hardware, no.

> It is not illegal to run macOS in a virtual machine on Apple hardware
>   for any macOS since Snow Leopard Server. It is against the Apple EULA
>   to run any macOS on non-Apple hardware, directly on the hardware or in
>   a virtual machine.

From https://www.quora.com/Is-it-illegal-to-run-OSX-in-a-virtual-machine-I-remember-Apple-saying-their-OS-was-free

Comment: is that illegal, If use it for personal use like just app testing?